# Group function in belongs_to association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

user.rb

```
enum gender: [:Male, :Female] 
belongs_to :qualification
```

qualification.rb

```
has_many :users
```

When I query

```
User.all.group(:gender).count.map { |k, v| [User.genders.key(k), v] }.to_h
```

It gives me

```
{"Male"=>18, "Female"=>1}
```

But I doesn't know to do same for qualification because association is involve in it.How I do it?

```
User.all.group(:qualification_id).count.map { ??? }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can perform a join between your associated models by using `joins()` with the name of the association, and then group by any column of the joined model.

For example, if you want to group by the `name` column of qualification :

```
User.joins(:qualification).group('qualifications.name').count
```

Use the symbol `:qualification` describing the relation in the `joins` method, but use the table name `'qualifications'` in the `group` method in order to specify the column. This will generate a SQL request like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(users.id)
FROM users
INNER JOIN qualifications ON users.qualification_id = qualifications.id
GROUP BY qualifications.name
```

- Documentation of ActiveRecord (search for `joins`) : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
- Explanation of SQL `JOINS` : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp