# How in ROR to group data by belongs_to relationships with another table and have the names of the group's arrays be names from the related table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've heard that you can do this via group_by rails, but I don't understand how.
Thank you in advance)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Can you give an example of the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not presented any schema of data, let's assume you have authors and books tables, each book belongs to an author.

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Retrieve books with included authors from DB and prepare a hash using `group_by` method. Please notice that `group_by` is a method of `Enumerable` module, not `ActiveRecord`.

```
Book.includes(:author).group_by(&:author)
```

You will get something like this, a hash with keys as authors with values as arrays of author's books:

```
{
  <Author id: 1, name: "Mark Twain"> => [
    <Book id: 1, title: "The Gilded Age", author_id: 1>,
    <Book id: 2, title: "Roughing It", author_id: 1>
  ],
  <Author id: 2, name: "Ernest Hemingway"> => [
    <Book id: 3, title: "The Sun Also Rises", author_id: 2>
  ]
}
```

If you want names as keys just use `group_by` with a block:

```
Book.includes(:author).group_by { |book| book.author.name }

{
  "Mark Twain" => [
    <Book id: 1, title: "The Gilded Age", author_id: 1>, 
    <Book id: 2, title: "Roughing It", author_id: 1>
  ], 
  "Ernest Hemingway" => [
    <Book id: 3, title: "The Sun Also Rises", author_id: 2>
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want but in general if you want to do `group_by` on `belongs_to` relationships yes you can.

I encourage you to checkout the following links:

- [Group function in belongs_to association rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086845/group-function-in-belongs-to-association-rails)
- [Doing group_by on class with belongs_to in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060443/doing-group-by-on-class-with-belongs-to-in-rails)